# Leaking water by bathtub

Tags: water, leaking

There is water slowly leaking by the bottom of the bathtub even when there is no water running.

We have called a plumber but I'm wondering what what the cause might be.

Comment: Maybe the faucet connection is leaking.

Comment: leaking cartridge

Comment: Outside the bathtub?  Telling you what the cause "Might" be will do you no good. Turn your main water supply off and wait for the plumber to arrive.

Comment: Water could be pooled under the tub and slowly oozing out.